# Does Google allow third-party email apps to establish and maintain an IMAP IDLE connection or similar connection with Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail

That way, the Gmail server can push new email to the app when it arrives, instead of the app having to poll the server.

Comment: I would expect them to support IDLE.  Why not try?

Comment: A quick search on your favourite search engine should answer this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Gmail's IMAP servers have supported IDLE [since day one](https://blogs.oracle.com/chienr/entry/gmail_supports_imap_idle).

*(I mean, why wouldn't they?)*